# How to play default sound when received remote APNs push in foreground？

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, system-sounds

Now，my app can play default sound when app is in background，but can not play default sound in forground ，why？Thanks

Comment: The basic idea of using notification would be to alert the user of a changes in the application data. Now if the application is already in the foreground, the user would be able to view the difference directly without a notification.

But if the requirement is such, you can use 
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1007)

The parameter has to be UInt32

Answer (score 0):

The big apple think: since the user is already foreground, so there is no need to alert user.
Actually if you want do some alert, you just do whatever you like by your code after receiving the notification.